Docker Composer change Image .env variable not working
I have ReactJs app with .env file like this:
REACT_APP_SERVER_URL="URL1"
Then I using Dockerfile to build to Image:
# Fetching the latest node image on apline linux
FROM node:22 AS builder
# Setting up the work directory
WORKDIR /app
# Installing dependencies
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copying all the files in our project
COPY . .
# Building dist and run
RUN npm run build

# # Fetching the latest nginx image
FROM nginx
# Copying built assets from builder
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copying our nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


After that, I pushed this Image to my reposity. Then I am using this Docker Composer file:
db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgress
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
      PGPORT: 5433
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    expose:
      - "5433"
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    restart: always

  server:
    image: my_server_image
    container_name: server
    platform: linux/amd64
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db

  react:
    image: my_web_image
    container_name: web
    depends_on:
      - server
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_SERVER_URL="New URL" <-----HERE
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"

But when run docker compose up, then run my web app, I still see the REACT_APP_SERVER_URL show "URL1", can someone help?
console.log('url', process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL)
 -> URL1


Front-end apps only use environment variables during the build phase. All their assets are statically compiled

Hi @Phil, did you mean I can not do that? I am new on Docker, thanks

Assuming your React app's build system is create-react-app (FYI that's a dead project, time to try something else like Vite), you'll want to create separate a .env.production file and use that in your production build. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Duplicate: How to set build .env variables when running create-react-app build script?.

@Phil thanks you, I read this topic before, my problem is I want to change the ENV variable programmatically without build the Image again. because I have to run this docker in 2 server (without know their IP after build Image), and I dont want to update .env file directly before build

You need to be aware that browsers run the React app code. You will need to point API calls to a publicly available address so for your production builds that would be your load balancer or whatever sits in front of your server instance(s)

hell thanks you, as you said I think there are no way to update ENV variable of Image,  by the way, I can update this variable each time using docker compose up
